# Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<IOfferingBadgeProps>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to define prop types where the type of `status` depends on whether `amount` exists.

```
export interface IOfferingBadgeBaseProps {
  badge?: string;
}

export type IOfferingBadgeProps = IOfferingBadgeBaseProps &
  (
    | {
        status?: EStatus;
      }
    | { status?: ETag; amount?: number }
  );

export const OfferingBadge: FunctionComponent<IOfferingBadgeProps> = function Badge({
  amount,
  status,
  badge,
}) {
  return null;
}
```

But I get an error `Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<IOfferingBadgeProps>'.ts(2339)`

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Im not sure whats the point to declare alternative types `{} | {}` if `amount` is optional. I would simply join them together. `IOfferingBadgeBaseProps & { status?: EStatus | ETag; amount?: number }`

Comment: I need to pass the `status` to another component's prop that accepts only `ETag`

Comment: Then assign a proper type to that component.

Comment: Are you saying that if `amount` is set, that `status` must also be set and can only be of the type `ETag`?  We can write that, but that's not what your code is saying here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to assert is that if an `amount` is included, `status` must be an `ETag` (is it optional or required)?  If there is no `amount`, then `status` should be `EStatus`.

You are close, but you need to make `amount` required in the second option and disallowed in the first option.  To disallow a property, we write either `amount?: never` or `amount?: undefined`.  Both are the same and mean that this property doesn't have to be set, but if it is set it can only be set to `undefined` and never to an actual value.

```
export type IOfferingBadgeProps = IOfferingBadgeBaseProps &
  (
    | { 
      status: EStatus; 
      amount?: never;
      }
    | { 
      status: ETag;
      amount: number;
      }
  );
```

You will be able to destructure `amount` because is it included in the type for both cases.  And you should be able to narrow the type of `status` by checking if `amount` exists.